# existence directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, gateaux-derivative

I've this function : $$  f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \dfrac{(1+x^2)x^2y^4}{x^4+2x^2y^4+y^8} \quad   \text{ for } \qquad  (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\ 0 \quad  \quad  \quad  \quad  \quad  \quad  \quad   \quad  \text{ for } \quad   (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$$

This function isn't continuous in $(0,0)$ so isn't differentiable in $(0,0)$.
But what can i said about the existence of all the directional derivatives in $(0,0)$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the directional derivative?

Comment: v is a unit vector , v=$(v_1,v_2)$.$\partial_{v}f=lim_{t->0} {{f(tv_1,tv_2)-f(0,0)}\over{t}}={{(v_2)^4}\over{(v_1)^2}}$